# Change values over specific indexes in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have a Series of flags in a DataFrame:

```
a=pd.DataFrame({'flag':[0,1,0,0,1]})
```

and I want to change the values of the flags which are in a specific indexes:

```
lind=[0,1,3]
```

This is a simple solution:

```
def chnflg(series,ind):
   if series.ix[ind]==0:
       series.ix[ind]=1
   else:
       series.ix[ind]=0

map(partial(chnflg,a),lind)
```

It works fine but there are two issues: the first is that it makes the changes in-place, while I would like a new series in DataFrame. This is not a big deal after all.

The second point is that it does not seems pythonic enough. Is it possible to do better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easier way to describe your function is as x -> 1 - x, this will be more efficient that apply/map.

```
In [11]: 1 - a.iloc[lind]
Out[11]: 
   flag
0     1
1     0
3     1
```

*Note: I like to use iloc here as it's less ambiguous.*

If you wanted to assign these inplace then do the explicit assignment:

```
In [12]: a.iloc[lind] = 1 - a.iloc[lind]

In [13]: a
Out[13]: 
   flag
0     1
1     0
2     0
3     1
4     1
```

Comment: I wanted all the values (changed and unchanged) and not in-place. In that case I can work around using your solution: a['nflag']=a['flag'] and then use your in-place solution

Answer (score 1):

You could create a dict that flips the values and call map, this would return a series and you can create a new dataframe and leave the original intact:

```
In [6]:

temp={0:1,1:0}

pd.DataFrame(a.ix[lind]['flag'].map(temp))

Out[6]:

   flag
0     1
1     0
3     1
```

Comment: I like that but I have an issue that I do not know how to fix it: the new dataframe contains only the valued changed, while I want both. Changed and unchanged.